# how to create key in javascript object using if else statement

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having difficulties to create new key in object using if else condition in javascript.here is an object:

```
userInfo: {
      userid: userInfo.userid,
      pid: userInfo.pid,
      usernameType: userInfo.usernameType,
      if(getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'userAcceptedCookie')=="true"){
        cookieAccept:'Y'
        cookieDateTime: getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'ad')
        sessionID : JSESSIONID
        cookieAcceptedProperty : getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'as');
        sessionDateTime :JSESSIONTIME;
      }
      else
      {
        cookieAccept:'N'
      },
      activeStatus: userInfo.activeStatus,
      age: userInfo.age,
      gender: userInfo.gender
    }
```

what i need is if my condition is true then create object

```
userInfo: {
  userid: userInfo.userid,
  pid: userInfo.pid,
  usernameType: userInfo.usernameType,
  cookieAccept:'Y'
  cookieDateTime: getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'ad')
  sessionID : JSESSIONID
  cookieAcceptedProperty : getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'as');
  sessionDateTime :JSESSIONTIME;
  activeStatus: userInfo.activeStatus,
  age: userInfo.age,
  gender: userInfo.gender
}
```

else

```
userInfo: {
  userid: userInfo.userid,
  pid: userInfo.pid,
  usernameType: userInfo.usernameType,
  cookieAccept:'N'
  activeStatus: userInfo.activeStatus,
  age: userInfo.age,
  gender: userInfo.gender
}
```

Comment: you can use condition while creating object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach is the following:

```
let userInfo = {
    userid: userInfo.userid,
    pid: userInfo.pid,
    usernameType: userInfo.usernameType,
    ...getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'userAcceptedCookie') && {
        cookieAccept: 'Y',
        cookieDateTime: getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'ad'),
        sessionID: JSESSIONID,
        cookieAcceptedProperty: getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'as'),
        sessionDateTime: JSESSIONTIME
    },
    ...!getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'userAcceptedCookie') && {
        cookieAccept: 'N'
    },
    activeStatus: userInfo.activeStatus,
    age: userInfo.age,
    gender: userInfo.gender
}
```

This is because the spread operator for object literals does nothing if its operand is an object without enumerable own properties [[See](http://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html)]

You can test a simplified version here:

```js
let userInfo = {
  userid: 1,
  ...false && {
    cookieAccept: 'Y',
    cookieDateTime: 1,
    sessionID: 1,
    cookieAcceptedProperty: 1,
    sessionDateTime: 1
  },
  ...true && {
    cookieAccept: 'N'
  },
  activeStatus: 2,
  age: 2,
  gender: 2
}

console.log(userInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an `if else` statement directly into an object declaration. What you can do is create the object with the static value, and use your `if else` to assign value to your object after the declaration. :

```
userInfo: {
  userid: userInfo.userid,
  pid: userInfo.pid,
  usernameType: userInfo.usernameType,
  activeStatus: userInfo.activeStatus,
  age: userInfo.age,
  gender: userInfo.gender
}

if (getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'userAcceptedCookie') == "true") {
  userInfo.cookieAccept = 'Y'
  userInfo.cookieDateTime = getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'ad')
  userInfo.sessionID = JSESSIONID
  userInfo.cookieAcceptedProperty = getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'as');
  userInfo.sessionDateTime = JSESSIONTIME;
} else {
  userInfo.cookieAccept = 'N'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your keys after the object litteral:

```js
var data = {
  userInfo: {
    userid: userInfo.userid,
    pid: userInfo.pid,
    usernameType: userInfo.usernameType,
    activeStatus: userInfo.activeStatus,
    age: userInfo.age,
    gender: userInfo.gender
};

if (getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C','userAcceptedCookie')=="true") {
  data.userInfo.cookieAccept:'Y';
  data.userInfo.ookieDateTime: getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'ad');
  data.userInfo.sessionID : JSESSIONID;
  data.userInfo.cookieAcceptedProperty : getCookieValue('JetPrivilege_CCounter_C', 'as');
  data.userInfo.sessionDateTime :JSESSIONTIME;
} else {
  data.userInfo.cookieAccept:'N';
}
```